# Extra named ranges appearing in named range loop

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I've been working on an Excel (Macro-enabled) document in Office 2010. I opened it on another computer with Office 2013 and I noticed that there were named ranges that I hadn't used. Here's a few of them:

```
LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR
LOCAL_DAY_FORMAT
LOCAL_HOUR_FORMAT
LOCAL_MINUTE_FORMAT
```

They aren't visible in the Name Manager and I'm not sure what put them there.

I have MySQL running on the second computer, but I turned it off and restarted Excel after seeing these. This didn't help.

Where are these named ranges from and are they important?

Comment: It looks like a MySql addin is the culprit. I googled "Excel LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR" and came up with this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26087354/293078.

Comment: @DougGlancy I found that too, and I diabled MySql and restarted Excel... but it's still there :(

Comment: Once they are there I wouldn't expect MySql to remove them, especially since it's because of a bug. You'll have to do that yourself. Just loop through and delete. Back up first!

Comment: @DougGlancy Ah! Thank you so much! That seems to have done it all. Stupid MySql. Also, thank you for saving my TicTacToe game ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun!