# Excel 4.0 funtion stored in defined names

Tags: excel, excel-4.0

I have a problem where excel is asking me to save my file as a xslm because it says I have Excel 4.0 stored in defined names, however, I do not have any names stored at all.
[Issue pop-up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7tq8.png)

My workbook is super simple, no macros, it only uses IFs and HLOOKUP formulas.

Also I explored other thread with a similar question, but the responses say to check for defined names and to disable the MySQL add or any other SQL connector, and I have neither of those (thread: [Excel issue "excel 4.0 function stored in defined names"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087354/excel-issue-excel-4-0-function-stored-in-defined-names)).

[No names defined screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zs5q.png).

[No SQL add ins enables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjVhr.png)

I'm using Microsoft 365 with 2018 version.

Anyone knows what else could it be?

Thanks

:)

Comment: Did you look for hidden names?

Comment: Yes, I used the following macro to find and delete any hidden name: Public Sub DEV_CheckNames()

Dim n As name
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Not n.Visible Then
        Debug.Print n.NameLocal, n.RefersToLocal
        n.Delete  
    End If
Next
End Sub

Comment: I suppose you could try saving it as an .xlsm, and then saving it as an .xlsx.  Or you could try opening in safe mode and seeing if you can save as xlsx.  If you have office 365, I've had good luck with the tech support division devoted to that product (not the general MS tech support).

Comment: Already tried saving as .xlsx in safe mode and it doesn't work, I will try looking with the Excel support then. Thanks Ron :)